# Using Array in '->where()' for Laravel Query Building

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to get all values of a column, and then use it in another query. I used `lists` and got the values as an array but, I couldn't find the way to check that variable (array containing each id) in other query

```
$subscribes = Subscribe::where('from_id', $currentUser)->lists('id')

// dd($subscribes), logs values as array.


$videos = Photo::where('id', $subscribes)->get();
```

This doesn't work because $subscribes is an array.

Should I use a for loop and send another query for each id? Or is there a practical way that I am missing out? What is the proper way of using it?

Comment: is it below one working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `whereIn` method:

```
$videos = Photo::whereIn('id', $subscribes)->get();
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries (scroll down / search 'whereIn')

Answer (score 1):

Apply `whereIn` method

```
if(is_array($subscribes) && count($subscribes) > 0){
    $videos = Photo::whereIn('id', $subscribes)->get();
}
```